# Solve product validation - Missing Bundle: org.eclipse.gef

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to export an old plugin (maintained by myself) as a product. The set up is a main plugin with fragments that are included into a feature. This is working and I can export the feature and install it into eclipse.

Recently I created a eclipse product and as content it includes my feature. In the content tab of the product I also added other features until one is missing:

```
Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gef; bundle-version="3.11.0"
```

This is the message I get using the validation. My problem is that I can not add org.eclipse.gef to the list of features, so it will not run or export.

If I add the plugin in Run -> Run configuration I can start it from eclipse, but it is missing for export.

Do I have to add a feature that includes org.eclipse.gef? What am I missing?

Comment: If your product build is based on features then, yes, you have to include a feature which contains GEF (or include the GEF plugins in your feature).

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a predefined feature... do not know why. Include GEF to my own feature is so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like greg-449 wrote in comments, I included org.eclipse.gef in my feature.